# why NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, ""); doesnot accept two parameters for oreo version

Tags: android, firebase

import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
 i used above header file for NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, "channelid") for creating notification but it shown error like below:

> Error:(37, 20) error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be
>   applied to given types; required: Context found: Context,String
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of the support library are you using? Should be at least 26.1.0. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+' i am using this library in my gradle

Comment: Don't use `+` there. Specify a version, at least 26.1.0, and resync.

Comment: Thanks its working now

Comment: it is not working in my case    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
I have used this

Comment: what type of error you got ?? show that error !! please @amin pinjari

Comment: try tis     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: My compile version is 27 and using compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1" gives me the same error

Comment: Included `implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1"` build gives me error when building....